# Changing multiple text layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, selections

Is there any way for me to change the contents of multiple text layers that have the same text at the same time rather than doing each one individually in Photoshop?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to change the text *contents*, you can highlight the text layers in the Layers Panel then click Edit -> Find and Replace Text to change the text content for all of them at once.

If you only need to change text *properties*, you can highlight all text layers by holding the Shift key then click. Then do the property changes that you need to do.